# How to view the code behind a function in a linked-to library e.g. OpenCV

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I am programming with Visual studio C++. I know that openCV is an open source library. So I should be able to see the code of any function or method.

Let's say for example that I want to see how the drawing function "circle" works(the code behind it). I right click the function "circle" inside the Visual Studio and choose "Go To Definition" and it shows me the the declaration of the function which is inside "core.hpp".

How can I view the code of the function? Thanks a lot.

Comment: "Open source" means the source is available, it doesn't necessarily mean it's installed in the right place for VS to find it automatically. The best way to do that would be to load OpenCV into your solution as well and link against that copy, but that isn't always practical e.g. if it's large or if it has complicated build steps. If, as it sounds like, you're linking against a pre-compiled library then your options are to download an identical copy of the source to your disk or browse on-line as in Leigh's answer.

Comment: Uau, I'm quite impressed about how fast the answers are coming in this forum :-).

Thanks for your help, I've just realised that all the open-source is inside the opencv folder I've downloaded.

Do I vote for a best answer or something? thanks again

Comment: You click on a big "tick" under the answer's score to mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source isn't necessarily downloaded in the Library, `.hpp` is a header file.

To view the source you may need to download it in the source format or find it online- this actual circle function does appear to be on the opencv mirror on GitHub here, though:

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/drawing.cpp#L1319